# How to set the first option as empty?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to set the first value of the select field as empty value. The example is hosted on https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xlcji.

At the moment, the dollar sign is set as default. However I would like to set an empty value as default.

Comment: Can you add your component here instead of linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it normally.

```
const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState("0");

<TextField
  id="outlined-select-currency-native"
  select
  label="Native select"
  value={currency}
  onChange={handleChange}
  SelectProps={{
    native: true
  }}
  helperText="Please select your currency"
  variant="outlined"
>
  <option value="0" disabled>-- select currency --</option>
  {currencies.map((option) => (
    <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </option>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

Comment: I have changed my example. Could you please take look.

Comment: <option value={gender.abbr} disabled>Select your gender</option>
You should set this value to "".

Comment: I have set the value to "" and still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```
     <option value=""></option>
      {currencies.map((option) => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </option>
      ))}
```

Comment: Would not add "empty" as a currency.